# Generating all permutations of a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings: `['red','blue','pink']` and I'm trying to generate a list of all permutations of the elements of the given list as follows:

```
['red', 'redblue', 'redbluepink', 'redpinkblue',
 'blue', 'bluered', 'bluepink', 'blueredpink', 'bluepinkred',
 'pink', 'pinkred', 'pinkblue', 'pinkredblue', 'pinkbluered']
```

I have managed to write the following code to generate all the forward permutations of the elements of a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

def all_permutations(list_of_strings):
    results = [''.join(list_of_strings[i:j]) for i, j in combinations(range(len(list_of_strings) + 1), 2)]

    return results

print(all_permutations(['red','blue','pink']))
```

However, this code only manages to generate all the forward permutations:

```
['red', 'redblue', 'redbluepink', 'blue', 'bluepink', 'pink']
```

Could anyone help me figure out a way to generate all the permutations of the elements from a list of strings?

Comment: You can loop over the length of colors, i.e. `i in [1, 2, 3]` and then chain `map(permutations, combinations(colors, i))`.

Comment: Why is `redpink` not in your expected output?

Comment: @cody I must have missed adding that in my expected output list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second parameter to [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), `r` to get the iterator you want:

```
from itertools import permutations

def all_permutations(x):
    for r in range(1, len(x) + 1):
        yield from permutations(x, r)
```

To combine the result:

```
[''.join(s) for s in all_permutations(['red', 'blue', 'pink'])]
```

Or

```
map(''.join, all_permutations(['red', 'blue', 'pink']))
```

This will give you an order different from the one in the question. You can impose the order you want by sorting according to the index in your original list:

```
items = ['red', 'blue', 'pink']
index = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(items)}
all_items = sorted(all_permutations(items), key=lambda item: tuple(index[x] for x in item))
all_items = [''.join(item) for item in all_items]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution may meet your needs. Your solution is using `itertools.combinations`, and the key difference between *permutations* and *combinations* is that order does not matter in combinations, such that `'redblue'` and `'bluered'` would not be unique.

```
from itertools import permutations

def all_permutations(l):
    o = []
    for x in range(1, len(l) + 1):
        o.extend([''.join(p) for p in list(permutations(l, x))])
    return o

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'pink']

print(all_permutations(colors))
```

Result:

```
['red', 'blue', 'pink', 'redblue', 'redpink', 'bluered', 'bluepink', 'pinkred', 'pinkblue', 'redbluepink', 'redpinkblue', 'blueredpink', 'bluepinkred', 'pinkredblue', 'pinkbluered']
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist np.. your solution is far more elegant than mine, but I will leave it here anyway, for contrast.. haha

Comment: You beat me to it, and it's really the same solution. I agree that you should definitely leave it. +1